# How to get the correct available size on Window (without all the decor elements)?

Tags: android, android-measure

Is there any way to get the available size on a window without decor elements (status bar, navigation bar and cut outs)?

I've tried using the `getSize` from `WindowManager.getDisplay()`, but for some reason, if the device does not have a display cut out, it does not disconsider the status bar area.